# Can I host a dedicated Xbox live or PSN server in the same way I can PC games

Tags: gaming, hosting

Is it possible for one to host their own dedicated Xbox live or PSN server. Or is the way that console game servers are modeled that only the vendors host them?

Comment: To those who have voted to close I have edited the question so it is more 'in line with the scope' pf super user. My original reason for asking the question was exploring the idea of doing this myself. I didn't realise that mentioning renting it would get people backs up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the answer is no.

XBL and PSN games are designed to run through their respective services.  However, that doesnt mean they are hosted on those machines.  Many online console games redirect to the publishers servers.  Unfortunately, for good or bad, this gives the the consoles and game publishers complete control.

I cant say with 100% certainty that there arent servers available for console games, however I have never see any.

Answer (score 1):

PSN and Xboxlive are closed systems.  no 3rd party hosting is available. For a time Halo was offering this sort of service so you could control map rotation and admin kick players.  It was bought directly through xbox live.